# Is pandas 'corr()' applied to automatic data normalization?

Tags: python, pandas

I have used pandas `corr()` method many times. But I don't know exactly if pandas `corr()` applies automatic data normalization. I know the fact that correlation must be done after data normalization.

My question is that if I use pandas `corr()` method to check the pearson correlation between various columns in the dataframe, does the pandas `corr()` method apply data normalization by itself?

I tried to check this using `StandardScaler` from scikit-learn. The correlations after normalizing the data are equal to those without applying normalization.

[After I tried to do it]
Oh.. I tried to check it using Scikit-learn StandardScaler. After that, The coefficient of the latter is equal to the former. Maybe pandas corr() is automatically using data normalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no clue what you mean by

> I know the fact that correlation must be done after data
> normalization.

If you do spearman correlation you don't need to normalize your variables.

Most likely you are referring to pearson correlation. From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient), it is:

> the covariance of two variables, divided by the product of their
> standard deviations; thus it is essentially a normalised measurement
> of the covariance, such that the result always has a value between −1
> and 1

So in any calculation of spearman, there is a step in the calculation to scale by your standard deviation.

If you scale your variable before hand with `StandardScaler()`, you are just dividing your variables by their standard deviation, which of course doesn't change the result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! yes! I mean the pearson corrlelation. I should have mentioned the specific correlation such as pearson. Due to you, I know the new fact that normalization don't need to be done in spearman. Thanks!